# MVC Net Core Collect Data from Multiple Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, viewmodel

How would I collect data from multiple pages?
Example I have application which will take data from multiple pages. There will be a Next Button on each screen.
Eg: Page 1 has name, page 2 has address, page 3 has Product information.

(1) Is it best to actually separate into three ViewModels classes for each page?

(2) Or Use TempData, which will roll previous data into the next page?

```
public CustomerOrder()
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }

    public string Address{ get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    public string ProductName{ get; set; }
    public int Quantity{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you should do both. Each page should have its own view model. After each post, you persist each posted model to `TempData`. On the last step, you pull all the previous models from `TempData` and, combined with the model that was just posted, build out whatever entity(ies) you're saving to the database.

Comment: Well, you *could*, but since HTTP is stateless, you're really not "building" on anything. You would have post everything that was posted before each time, which means each step gets progressively more complex, with a greater chance of losing or corrupting data. Using `TempData` with separate view models keeps each step simple and focused only on that one step, not all the steps that came before.

Comment: As an alternative, you could also just do one post, and "fake" the steps using JavaScript to hide/show select portions of the form. It's a bit more complex on the front end, but then you're one and done on the backend.

Comment: thanks, I think java script may be the route also, Thank you, thanks are you going more responsive, and angular these days